# how to install qjackctl-0.9.6 from source

Tags: software-installation, jack

i am on ubuntu 20.04.3.tried to install qjackctl-0.9.6 (latest version) from source following instructions as given in https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/

got the following errors:

[image]

```
mee@mee-Inspiron-3543:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x  main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x  main
```

any help? tnx.

Comment: Some of your sources lists are corrupt. Please add text output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` to the question by editing  it.

Comment: just edited the question as asked!

Comment: To fix it use `sudo sed -i "s/main/focal main/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again. If you have errors, please show them.

Comment: that worked. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I should inform you about the prebuilt binary qjackctl-0.9.6 package in the [Rui Nuno Capela's Applications PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erncbc/+archive/ubuntu/apps-focal), it is installable by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rncbc/apps-focal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qjackctl
```

and then simply start using it.

---

Or if you are sure about the compilation path, you have to use the following steps to compile from source:

1. Enable Source Code (*deb-src*) repositories using Software & Update (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Get fresh packages lists and build-dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get build-dep qjackctl
   ```
3. Get and compile the source

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cmake debhelper-compat qttools5-dev
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget -c https://download.sourceforge.net/qjackctl/qjackctl-0.9.6.tar.gz
   tar -xf qjackctl-0.9.6.tar.gz
   cd qjackctl-0.9.6
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qjackctl/qjackctl_0.9.6-1.debian.tar.xz
   tar -xf qjackctl_0.9.6-1.debian.tar.xz
   rm qjackctl_0.9.6-1.debian.tar.xz
   mv ../qjackctl-0.9.6.tar.gz ../../qjackctl_0.9.6.orig.tar.gz
   dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
   sudo apt-get install ../qjackctl_0.9.6-1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Use compiled application.

Comment: tried the first solution and got:mee@mee-Inspiron-3543:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rncbc/apps-focal
[sudo] password for mee: 
 Applications for xUbuntu 20.04 LTS (focal)
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~rncbc/+archive/ubuntu/apps-focal
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.